# How to solve size mismatch problem in loading a pretrained model in pytorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

I am trying to load a pretrained model in which the number of filters (channels) of conv layers is `64`, into a model with `128` filters in conv layers. I use `new_network.load_state_dict(pretrained_model, strict=False)` but I face size mismatch error for all of that layers.
How can I initialize some of the filters in each conv layer with available pretrained model weights?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, a layer's weight is very much dependent on its number of channels. What might be possible (depending on your requirements), is adding extra convolutional layers after the pretrained model architecture, and use the pretrained weights for the original layers, so essentially transfer learning.